# Populate a 2D Array

Tags: excel, vba

Still trying to load excel datas in a VBA array that I want to use as a single bloc to send in SQL/databse.
Anyway, I have some issues with the loop structure here. I got the error 9 : Subscript out of range for this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim xrow As Long, xcol As Long
Dim rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long, i As Long, j As Long

rowIndex = 0
colIndex = 0
xrow = 1
xcol = 1

'outer loop down rows

Do Until Cells(xrow, xcol).Value = ""

    'inner loop across columns

    Do Until Cells(xrow, xcol).Value = ""
        myArray(rowIndex, colIndex) = Cells(xrow, xcol).Value
        colIndex = colIndex + 1 ' increase array in 2nd dimension
    xcol = xcol + 1 'increase column on worksheet
    Loop

xcol = 0 'reset after finishing row loop
colIndex = 0 'reset 2nd dimension index in array
xrow = xrow + 1 'increase row on worksheet
rowIndex = rowIndex + 1 ' increase array in 1st dimension
Loop

End Sub
```

My table in excel is a 60 cells table starting from A1 to D15.

Thank in advance for your help ! It has to miss a tiny thing but what ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the worksheet range is fixed then:

```
Sub Populate2DArray()
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    myArray = Range("A1:D15")
End Sub
```

If the range does not have fixed boundries then:

```
Sub Populate2DArray_2()
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    myArray = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.
Unfortunately that does not work. However, when I try this:
 "Redim myArray(rowIndex, colIndex)" just above 
"myArray(rowIndex, colIndex) = Cells(xrow, xcol).Value" 

that populate the first row but stopping at the end of the loop or let's say trying to come back on the next outer loop

Comment: actually it selects the 15 rowsin excel properly filling my table myArray but it breaks at the end of the code giving the 1004 runtime error. Maybe I should add something to stop the loop at the end ?

Comment: @Pierre_CM: Are you talking about the answer code or about your code? If about the above code, it does not involve any iteration. It loads first 15 rows (only 15, as you required).

Comment: I was talking about the above code, basically, .currentregion selects all the rows and columns from cell "A1" and put them into my table myArray. But can I use this input (my table variable myArray) to send it into my SQL server ?

Comment: @Pierre_CM: It depends... Does your SQL server need the columns headers? Anyhow, why do not try it if accepts an array?

Comment: @FaneDuru Basically, I receive every morning the exact same excel table but only some random cells change. So I need this table to be sent into a SQL server on which I could apply some queries and play with my datas. As I won't be the only one to use the excel file, basically people need to just come into the file, click on a macro button and send the file to the SQL server. That's why I needed a quick macro. If I can populate the  excel table with the prop' .CurrentRegion it's fine but I need to find a way to send the variable "myArray" that represents the excel table directly to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic arrays can only increase the last dimension.
One-dimensional arrays can be increased because the first dimension is the last dimension. In the case of more than two dimensions, that is, only two dimensions can increase the size. In case of 3D, only 3D can increase the size.

So I'm pointing out how to make your 2D dynamic array wrong.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    ' One-Dimension
    Dim oneDim()
    For i = 1 To 5
        ReDim Preserve oneDim(1 To i)
        oneDim(i) = i
    Next i

    'two-Dimension
    Dim twoDim()
    For i = 1 To 5
        ReDim Preserve twoDim(1 To 3, 1 To i)
        twoDim(1, i) = i
        twoDim(2, i) = i + 1
        twoDim(3, i) = i + 2
    Next i

    'Three-Dimension
    Dim ThreeDim()
    For i = 1 To 5
        ReDim Preserve ThreeDim(1 To 3, 1 To 2, 1 To i)
        For j = 1 To 3
            For k = 1 To 2
                ThreeDim(j, k, i) = i
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    Stop
End Sub
```

### Image

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing this. I understand your point that only the last dimension of a dynamic array changes and I see what you mean by your code but would you mind to help me to adapt your idea to my code ? Because, in my example, my 2D array  goes down 15 rows and can change in the time so I need to make the number of rows variable. For the column it's the same but less tricky given the number of columns should stay the same.